# How to check the value passed into the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

The details are being fetched in the controller correctly but value passed in the view is incorrect. Therefore I am getting the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int64', but this >dictionary requires a model item of type >'estatebranch.ViewModels.RentRegisterViewModel'

My controller has following action method

```
public ActionResult RentRegister(int propertyId)
{
    try
    {       
        using (estatebranchEntities db = new estatebranchEntities())
        {
            RentRegisterViewModel objRentRegister = new RentRegisterViewModel();
            objRentRegister.balance = db.PropertyDetails.Where(m => m.propertyid == propertyId).Select(m => m.balance).SingleOrDefault();
            return View(objRentRegister.balance);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My View model is as follow:

```
public class RentRegisterViewModel
{
    public int recordid { get; set; }
    public int propertyid { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public long amountpaid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime paymentdate { get; set; }
    public long interest { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> balance { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyDetail PropertyDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no point to catching an exception if you're simply going to rethrow it.

Comment: If the view expects to get a model why are you giving it just the `balance`?

Comment: Presumably you meant `return View(objRentRegister)` rather than `return View(objRentRegister.balance)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line:

```
return View(objRentRegister);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is it possible that I pass the `balance` in the viewbag

Comment: your balance is in  "Model.balance" in your view

Comment: The view model fills the default values in other fields also. How can I avoid it?